# How to free a session variable in Liferay?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme

In Liferay, I'm using session variables for InterPortlet Communication.

```
PortletSession psession = request.getPortletSession();
String userId = (String) psession.getAttribute("userId", PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE);
```

After use of this variable, I want to destroy it.

How to destroy, scrap the session variables in liferay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use removeAttribute method of PortletSession. It will remove attribute from session.

In your case `psession.removeAttribute("userId");`

This is applicable to request and session attributes also.